# How to set time only in this format (hh:mm:ss) 00:00:00 with all values 0

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm able to set time in other formats but I'm not able to set time in this format, please help me.

I tried all the methods which i have up to my knowledge, I'm not able to set time with set() methods.

Comment: try with: `const d = new Date(); d.setHours(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: Please include the question in the question, don't leave it in the title.